# Why is ngrok actively refusing my connection attempts?

Tags: python, c#, sockets, ngrok

I have created a tcp server using sockets in python that will be hosted on a pi (but is being hosted on my laptop for now.)

All connections work fine when not using ngrok. I simply use the local IP on my network, and the client (an android app made using unity connects.)

I am going to be working on a network that doesn't allow for connections within the network, and a previous solution had been to use ngrok on the server machine to allow clients to connect. I just tried to test this on my home network, but it isn't working anymore. I last used it about half a year ago and it worked fine then.

Neither the unity android app, nor the quick python client that I knocked up to test it would connect to the server. I get this error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 8, in 
> pi.connect(serverAddress)
> ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

I get a similar message from the android (c#) client:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
fingerControl:connectToServer () (at Assets/fingerControl.cs:150)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/EventSystem.cs:514)

I don't remember doing anything differently to last time I used sockets with ngrok. Here are the relevant bits of code on

The server:

```
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serverAddress = ("", 5005)
server.bind(serverAddress)
server.listen(1)
print("Waiting for connection")
pc, add = server.accept()
print(pc.recv(1024))
pc.send("Connected".encode())
```

The c# client:

```
ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(addressBox.text.Remove(addressBox.text.Length - 1));
remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, Convert.ToInt32(portBox.text.Remove(portBox.text.Length - 1)));
server = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
server.Connect(remoteEP);
```

The python client:

```
pi = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ip = input("Enter IP: ")
port = int(input())
serverAddress = (ip, port)
pi.connect(serverAddress)

pi.send("Confirm".encode())
print(pi.recv(1024).decode())
```

Comment: "actively refused" means that the port isn't listening at the server IP, as opposed to a timeout due to a firewall blocking it.  The code shown (for Python at least, my C# is rusty but it looks right) is correct other than missing `import socket` (why do people leave out imports??)  Are you sure you typed the IP/port correctly on the python client?

Comment: This error message means the client computer sent a connection request message to the server computer, and the server computer said "wrong address, go away". This typically happens because no program on the server computer is listening on that port. I notice this server program only waits for one connection, then quits after that. If you try to make two connections, the server program will accept the first one and quit, and the server's operating system will tell the second client to go away because no server program is running any more.

Comment: Yes, you're both correct. Sorry for leaving out the import, I just copied the relevant code, and left out the unnecessary bits and forgot about the import. The problem isn't to do with my code as far as I can tell, because it works when not using ngrok. The problem only happens when using ngrok, which is why I'm stumped. The IPs are correct and there was never more that one client trying to connect to the server